# setting the HTML textbox value based on the selected option using Javascript function. But it seems to be not working

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript snippet which assigns the selected option value to a text box

```
function check() {
 document.getElementById("inp").value=document.getElementById("id").value ;
}
```

this is the actual html code

```
<form>
<select id="id"  onSelect="check( );">
<option></option>
<option value=85.5>opt1</option>
<option value=95.5>opt2</option>
<option value=95.5>opt3</option>
<option value=95.5>opt4</option>
</select>
<input type=text name="input" id="inp">
</form>
```

I Hope am done right ,but still am not able to get my solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's your fix.

This one works

I guess the summary of it is that you should change onSelect to onChange.

```
<script>
 function check() {
     document.getElementById("inp").value=document.getElementById("id").value;
    } 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="id"  onChange="check();">
        <option></option>
        <option value=85.5>opt1</option>
        <option value=95.5>opt2</option>
        <option value=95.5>opt3</option>
        <option value=95.5>opt4</option>
        </select>
    <input type=text name="input" id="inp" value="">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: and do `onChange="check(this)"` so you can do `function check(theSel) { theSel.form.input.value=theSel.value }` if it must be inline

Comment: Not to mention that all of this could be handled much more elegantly with jQuery altogether

Comment: Yes. Exactly. jQuery all the things

Comment: So we load a framework to be able to do `$(function() { $("#id").on("change",function() { $("#inp").val($(this).val()) }); });` instead of `window.onload=function() { document.getElementById("id").onchange=function() { this.form.input.value=this.value }}` I am not really convinced that is necessary

Comment: Depends, usually there's a lot more javascript going in a site than what we see in this little snippet. I'm sure there would be a lot more if we could see the full site. If, however, that's the only place then yeah I wouldn't recommend jQuery either

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this html

```
<select id="id">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="85.5">opt1</option>
  <option value="95.5">opt2</option>
  <option value="95.5">opt3</option>
  <option value="95.5">opt4</option>
</select>
```

You can use unobtrusive JavaScript and add this to the head

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() { 
  document.getElementById("id").onchange=function() {     
    this.form.input.value=this.value; 
  }
}
```

Same in jQuery would be

```
$(function() { 
  $("#id").on("change",function() { 
    $("#inp").val($(this).val()); 
  }); 
});
```

If you MUST do it inline, then

```
<select id="id" onchange="this.form.input.value=this.value;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You HTML has multiple issues as well as your javascript

Your formatted HTML

```
<form>
<select id="id" onChange="check();">
    <option></option>
    <option value="85.5">opt1</option>
    <option value="95.5">opt2</option>
    <option value="95.5">opt3</option>
    <option value="95.5">opt4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="input" id="inp" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("inp").value = document.getElementById("id").value;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4HmG2/)

Also you should enclose you values like value="". Besides this no major issues