# Pass dropdown values to text box with javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't know much about javascript and unfortunately don't have time to learn before this project is due (wish I did!). I assume it is possible to pass the value of a drop-down selection into a hidden text input field on a form before the form is submitted. Could anyone help me figure out how to do that with javascript? Thank you! Here are my drop-down and text box details:

```
<div class="formEntryArea">
<div class="formEntryLabel">
    <span class="formLabel"><label for=" langdropdown">Would you like to receive library notices in English or Spanish? ><span class="formRequired">*</span></label></span>
</div>
    <div class="formMultiSelect" id=”langdropdown”>
<select name=" langdropdown ">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Choose language</option>
<option value="eng">English</option>
<option value="spa">Spanish</option>
<input type="text" id="ddepartment" name="ddepartment"  value=””>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting the HTML textbox value based on the selected option using Javascript function. But it seems to be not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859130/setting-the-html-textbox-value-based-on-the-selected-option-using-javascript-fun)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 2):

This is simply. First of all, you have to bind a `change` event handler for your `select`. Then, you have to set `input` text with `value` selected from `dropdown`.

```js
var select=document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
var input=document.getElementById('ddepartment');
select.onchange=function(){
  input.value=select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<div class="formEntryArea">
<div class="formEntryLabel">
    <span class="formLabel"><label for=" langdropdown">Would you like to receive library notices in English or Spanish? ><span class="formRequired">*</span></label></span>
</div>
<div class="formMultiSelect" id=”langdropdown”>
    <select name=" langdropdown ">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose language</option>
       <option value="eng">English</option>
       <option value="spa">Spanish</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="ddepartment" name="ddepartment">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alexandru-Ionut Mihai! I will give all of these options a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
var myselect = document.getElementById("MySelect");
myselect.onchange = function(){
    alert(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);
    document.getElementById("ddepartment").value = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/fh5myefw/

Comment: Thank you CMedina!!

Answer (score 0):

Mind to close the tags, it's better practice.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('selectElem');
var outputElem = document.getElementById('ddepartment');

select.addEventListener('change',function(){
  var newValue = !this.selectedIndex ? "":this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  outputElem.value = newValue;
});
```

```html
    
<select name="langdropdown" id="selectElem" required>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Choose language</option>
  <option value="eng">English</option>
  <option value="spa">Spanish</option>
</select>  
<input type="text" id="ddepartment" name="ddepartment" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

this is javascript function

`function func(selectObject)
        {
            document.getElementById('ddepartment').value = selectObject.value;
        }`

add onchange event to select element like this

`<select name="langdropdown" onchange="func(this)">`

Comment: They are being lazy and asking us to do their homework. Not to mention three other people have already answered. Why would you post an answer?

Comment: Thank you very much, BARNI!! I have tried many different iterations of what you posted and just don't know enough to get it working. I will try some more.

Answer (score 0):

Here use this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('lang');

sel.onchange = function() {
  var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var che = document.getElementById('cache').value;
  che = val;
  console.log(che);
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('lang');

sel.onchange = function() {
  var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var che = document.getElementById('cache').value;
  che = val;
  console.log(che);
}
```

```html
<select id='lang' name="lang">
  <option value="" selected>Choose language</option>
  <option value="eng">English</option>
  <option value="spa">Spanish</option>
  <option value="jpn">Japanese</option>
  <option value="zho">Chinese</option>
  <option value="fin">Finnish</option>
  <option value="nav">Navajo</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="cache" name="cache" value=””>
```

Comment: Thank you very much zer00ne!! I will give all of these options a try tomorrow.